# Can't make right for loop

Tags: android, listview, for-loop

I try to parse HTML page with JSOUP and my problem is that I need to get all titles (there are only 10) and images (there are too). So I must situate they in the same place (news feed). So I try to do it with this loop

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {


    Document doc;
    try {

        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/news/").get();

        title = doc.select("h2[class=et_pt_title]");
        picture = doc.select("img");


          for (Element titles : title) {
              FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
              item.setTitle(titles.text());
              Log.w("title", "" + item.getTitle());
              for (Element img : picture) {

                //  feedList.add(item);

                  String iurl;
                  iurl = img.absUrl("src");

               //   FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                  if (iurl.contains("http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/")) {
                      item.setAttachmentUrl(iurl);
                  }
                  Log.w("imgUrl", "" + item.getAttachmentUrl());

              }

              feedList.add(item);

          }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

But the titles are situated right and `ListView` contains only 10 rows, but every row contains the same picture. How I must change my loop `for`? I want picture - title for each row, where different rows contains different pictures and titles.

My HTML looks like

```
<h2 class="et_pt_title">
    <a href="http://example.com/fotoshkola-yuurgu-otkryvaet-svoi-dveri/">&#171;Фотошкола &#187; открывает свои двери</a>
</h2>

<p class="et_pt_blogmeta">
    27.08.2014 &nbsp 
    <a href="http://example.com/category/abiturientam/" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике &laquo;Абитуриентам&raquo;" rel="category tag">Абитуриентам</a>, 
    <a href="http://example.com/category/aktual-noe/" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике &laquo;Актуальное&raquo;" rel="category tag">Актуальное</a>, 
    <a href="http://example.com/category/tvorchestvo/" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике &laquo;Творчество&raquo;" rel="category tag">Творчество</a>, 
    <a href="http://example.com/category/fotoshkola/" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике &laquo;Фотошкола&raquo;" rel="category tag">Фотошкола</a>, 
    <a href="http://example.com/category/hochu-v-gu/" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике&raquo;" rel="category tag">ba</a>
</p>

<div class="et_pt_thumb2 alignleft">
    <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/3kSAbKRKwHM-282878_120x120.jpg" alt='&#171;Фотошкола &#187; открывает свои двери' width='120px' height='120px' />
    <a href="http://example.com/fotoshkola-otkryvaet-svoi-dveri/"></a>
</div> <!-- end .thumb -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding images, what you're basically doing is:

1. Loop all titles (`title`) and in each iteration:
2. Loop all images (`pictures`)
3. Pick an image (`img`) that meets the condition (`if(iUrl.contains...`)

If one or more of the images meet the condition (3.), then **the last iterated image to meet the condition gets it's url set to the `item#attachmentUrl`** (property name assumed from setter name).

What you probably want is to **pick the nearest image after your** `h2` within the `title`-loop:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {


    Document doc;
    try {

        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/news/").get();

        title = doc.select("h2[class=et_pt_title]");

        for (Element titles : title) {
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setTitle(titles.text());

            Log.w("title", "" + item.getTitle());

            // From Jsoup doc:
            // siblingA ~ siblingX: finds sibling X element preceded by sibling A, e.g. h1 ~ p
            // :eq(n): find elements whose sibling index is equal to n; e.g. form input:eq(1)
            Elements imgContainingDiv = doc.select("h2[class=et_pt_title] ~ div[class=et_pt_thumb2]:eq(0)") // THIS MIGHT NEED TO BE :eq(1)!
            Elements picture = imgContainingDiv.select("img")

            for (Element img : picture) {

            //  feedList.add(item);

              String iurl;
              iurl = img.absUrl("src");

            //   FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
              if (iurl.contains("http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/")) {
                  item.setAttachmentUrl(iurl);
              }
              Log.w("imgUrl", "" + item.getAttachmentUrl());

            }

            feedList.add(item);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me :( I tried to change :eq(0) to :eq(1) and even erase it.

Comment: What version of Jsoup are you using? If a recent one, you could try:
"h2.et_pt_title ~ div.et_pt_thumb2:eq(0)" or "h2.et_pt_title ~ div.et_pt_thumb2.alignleft:eq(0)".

Comment: I use jsoup-1.7.3. Consider that problem is not in syntax but I'll try